# UNIX timestamp of date on midnight UTC+0

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following date: **07/08/2018** in the format **m/d/Y**. This date is july 08, 2018.

And I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var dateFrom = '07/08/2018';
    dateFrom = new Date(dateFrom);
alert(dateFrom);
```

When I do this, I get the following result:

```
Sun Jul 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)
```

As you can see, because I live in Belgium, I get the time + GMT+2. But that's not what I want. I want the **exact** UNIX timestamp of 07/08/2018 (or any other date) of GMT+0.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var dateFrom = '07/08/2018';
    dateFrom = Math.floor((new Date(dateFrom)).getTime()/1000);
alert(dateFrom);
```

If I execute this code, I get the following result:

```
1531000800
```

But that's not what I want. If I check the UNIX timestamp I get (1531000800) on this (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) website, I get the following result:

```
1531000800
Is equivalent to:
07/07/2018 @ 10:00pm (UTC)
```

I want the UNIX timestamp that is equal to 07/08/2018 @ 00:00am (UTC).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), underneath `dateString` I read “... Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.” In other words, if you used the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which is **much** better than the `mm/dd/yyyy` format, you would automatically get a `Date` at 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MDM documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC#Examples):

> The following statement creates a Date object using UTC instead of local time:

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Code Sample:

```js
var date = new Date()
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()))

console.log(date)
console.log(utcDate)
```

Comment: the above code sample answer works for the HubSpot API when the property type is date.

`+ utcDate`